# Directly proportional to which?

Tags: relations

This might be a simple question, but the exact wording of this statement is important. If I know that the relationship between two variables is this:

$$\gamma \propto  \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$

Is the appropriate way to write that in a sentence: 'y is inversely proportional to k' or should it be 'y is inversely proportional to the square root of k'.

If somebody could explain *why* whichever is correct is correct, that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

I would take "$y$ is inversely proportional to $k$" to mean $y=c/k$ for some constant $c$, so for your situation I'd definitely say "$y$ is inversely proportional to the square root of $k$."

Comment: Okay, but you would still say that 'the relationship between y and k is inversely proportional'? (slightly different wording)

Comment: @user10265: I wouln't, and I hope no careful person would.  One **might** say "there is an inverse relationship" to mean that as one increases, the other decreases.